# apache configs for graphite webapp for custom prefix

Tags: apache, graphite

I am trying to setup graphite webapp for graphite on a linux hosts. i am running into issues while setting up the apache configs, especially in setting up a custom url.

Our apache url always renders urls of the form `http://internalapps.com/INT/<appname>` . So i am trying to setup graphite webapp to be rendered as **http://internalapps.com/INT/graphite**

Our graphite setup is located on the disk at **/home/internal/tools/graphite/**

My problem is that when I restart apache after apllying these changes , the url http://internalapps.com/INT/graphite does not resolve to any address. I do not see any errors in my apache logs

```
WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgi

<VirtualHost *:5002>
        ServerName stagehost2
        DocumentRoot "/home/internal/tools/graphite/webapp"
        ErrorLog /home/internal/tools/graphite/storage/log/webapp/error.log
        CustomLog /home/internal/tools/graphite/storage/log/webapp/access.log common

        # I've found that an equal number of processes & threads tends
        # to show the best performance for Graphite (ymmv).
        WSGIDaemonProcess graphite processes=5 threads=5 display-name='%{GROUP}' inactivity-timeout=120
        WSGIProcessGroup graphite
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        WSGIImportScript /home/internal/tools/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi process-group=graphite application-group=%{GLOBAL}

        # XXX You will need to create this file! There is a graphite.wsgi.example
        # file in this directory that you can safely use, just copy it to graphite.wgsi
        WSGIScriptAlias /INT /home/internal/tools/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi

        Alias /content/ /home/internal/tools/graphite/webapp/content/
        <Location "/content/">
                SetHandler None
        </Location>


        Alias /media/ "/home/internal/tools/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/"
        <Location "/media/">
                SetHandler None
        </Location>

        <Directory /home/internal/tools/graphite/conf/>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You should be using the URL ``http://internalapps.com:5002/INT/graphite`` for a start based on that configuration.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton we have a Vip backed by a cluster  of apache servers , so internalapps.com maps to that cluster. for ex internalapps.com maps to stagehost1:5002 , stagehost2:5002 and so on

Comment: Why is there no ServerName directive in the VirtualHost? Was that left out for the post?

Comment: Are you referring to this      "  ServerName graphite". It is the first line that follows the start of the Virtual host

Comment: Sorry, meant to say that it doesn't match either the URL you are using, or the name 'stagehost1' or 'stagehost2'. The ServerName value must match the host name appearing in the URL which any front end proxy uses in the URL when proxying to the back end. So if the proxy URL wasn't ``http://graphite/INT/...`` it will no match that VirtualHost.

Comment: ok got you let me try that

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I tried that but still no luck.

Comment: Are you able to access the backend directly, without going through the proxy? Use curl on the actual host if you need to. What is the URL that works for that?

Comment: We can never access the backend urls as a security measure . The frontend vip puts in security tokens which cannot be replicated via curl on the raw apache host:port combination . :(

Comment: What verifies the tokens on the backend? The web application or Apache?  If the web application, that you get a failure from the web application level because of the missing security tokens will at least tell you if when accessing the backend directly with curl that it got sent to the correct application. You could also replace the WSGI script temporarily with a WGSI hello world to verify that is where it is ending up.

Comment: Let me try the idea of wsgi script.the verification of tokens is done by a orchestration layer that sits on top of the apache clusters (and is not owned by us).